# Pointer instantly 0x0

Tags: c++, pointers, gtkmm

i have this code. the pointer turns 0x0 immediately before using it. short before, it had the correct address.

```
TreeViewColumn *col;
col = preview->get_column(pcFolder); /* col = 0x7fff5fc404a0 */
col->set_resizable(true);            /* col = 0x0 */
```

i use Gtkmm 2.4, but it returns the expected value, it just turns 0x0. whats wrong?

gdb proof:

```
151             col = preview->get_column(pcFolder); /* col = 0x7fff5fc404a0 */
(gdb) print col
$1 = ('Gtk::TreeViewColumn' *) 0x7fff5fc404a0
(gdb) print *col
warning: can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `Gtk::TreeViewColumn' value
$2 = {
  <Gtk::Object> = {
    <Glib::Object> = {
      <Glib::ObjectBase> = <invalid address>, 
      members of Glib::Object: 
      _vptr$Object = 0x7fff5fc06a20, 
      static object_class_ = {<No data fields>}
    }, 
    members of Gtk::Object: 
    static object_class_ = {<No data fields>}, 
    referenced_ = 21, 
    gobject_disposed_ = 60
  }, 
  members of Gtk::TreeViewColumn: 
  static treeviewcolumn_class_ = {<No data fields>}
}
(gdb) next
152             col->set_resizable(true);            /* col = 0x0 */
(gdb) print col
$3 = ('Gtk::TreeViewColumn' *) 0x0
(gdb) print *col
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
(gdb) next

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x00000001000edc68 in Gtk::TreeViewColumn::set_resizable ()
```

i have no idea what causes this phenomenon. do you have?

**Solution:**
reading the documentation. the function returning pcFolder counts from 1, get_column() from 0.

Comment: what does `get_column` look like?

Comment: http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm/2.22/classGtk_1_1TreeView.html#a513e50ad0acdd817d1a443f1eaa3debe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function call:

```
preview->get_column(pcFolder);
```

returns NULL.

When gdb shows the current code line, it hasn't been executed until you type next.

You probably pass an index that is larger than the number of columns in `preview`. Try:

```
p pcFolder
p preview->get_columns().size()
```

Comment: i get these: (gdb) p pcFolder
$6 = 5
(gdb) p preview->get_columns().size()

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x00000001000e7f7c in Gtk::TreeView::get_columns ()

Comment: and pcfolder is set via: int pcFolder = preview->append_column("Folder", cFolder);

Comment: Sorry, I think it should have been p preview->get_columns().size()

Comment: And append_column() returns the number of columns after appending, so it's always one higher then the last column index.

Answer (score 2):

`preview->get_column();` returns NULL, before that, its just some random value, since you didn't initialize the `col` variable

Answer (score 2):

Better code would actually be to initialise the variable immediately on use by calling getColumn at the point of declaration:

`TreeViewColumn *col = preview->get_column(pcFolder);`

If this function can return NULL (as it appears to) you must then check before you use the pointer, thus:

```
if( col != NULL )
{
   col->set_resizable( true );
}
// else handle the "error" if you want
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preview->get_column(pcFolder)
```

must be returning 0.